# Loop through each variable and collect output R

Tags: r, loops

I have a data frame that looks like this.  names and number of columns will NOT be consistent (sometimes 'C' will not be present, other times "D', 'E', 'F' may be present, etc.)

```
# name and number of columns varies...so need flexible process
A <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 4, 8)
B <- c(5, 6, 6, 5, 3, 7, 2, 1, 1, 2, 7, 4, 7, 8, 5, 7, 6, 6, 4, 7)
C <- c(9, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 89, 9, 7, 6, 5, 6, 8, 9 , 67, 6)
ABC <- data.frame(A, B, C)
```

I want to loop through each variable and collect various information.  This is a simple example, but what I am doing will be more complicated.  I say that so that somebody doesn't just recommend some sort of summary() type solution.

```
maximum_value <- max(A)
mean_value <- mean(A)
# lots of other calculations for A
ID = 'A'

tempA <- data.frame(ID, maximum_value, mean_value)

maximum_value <- max(B)
mean_value <- mean(B)
# lots of other calculations for B
ID = 'B'

tempB <- data.frame(ID, maximum_value, mean_value)

maximum_value <- max(C)
mean_value <- mean(C)
# lots of other calculations for C
ID = 'C'

tempC <- data.frame(ID, maximum_value, mean_value)

output <- rbind(tempA, tempB, tempC)
```

Here is my attempt at creating a loop to go through the variables one by one and aggregate output.  I can't figure out how to get [i] to point at an individual column of the data frame ABC.

```
# initialize data frame
data__ <- data.frame(ID__ = as.character(),
                     max__ = as.numeric(),
                     mean__ = as.numeric())

# loop through A, then B, then C
for(i in A:C) {
  ID__ <- '[i]'
  max__ <- maximum[i]
  mean__ <- mean[i]
  data__temp <- (ID__, max__, mean__)
  data__ <- rbind(data__, data__temp)
}
```

If I were doing this in SAS, I would use a select into within proc sql to create a list of the variable names, then write an array, then i could loop through them that way, but there's something I'm missing here.

How would I tell R to do this process for each variable in the data frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the tidyverse dplyr and tidyr package, you can do

```
library(tidyr)
ABC %>% gather(ID, value) %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarize_all(funs(mean, max))
```

or

```
ABC %>% gather(ID, value) %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
    summarize(maximum_value = max(value), mean_value=mean(value))
```

If you'd rather use base functions and there are a lot of "weird" functions, you can use `purrr`'s map_df function

```
library(purrr)
map2_df(ABC, names(ABC), function(a, n) {
    data_frame(ID=n, max_val=max(a), mean_val=mean(a))
})
```

Comment: I don't think this addresses the two main problems with my scenario.  The first being that the names and number of variables will not be consistent.  Second, I am doing more than just calculating summary stats...just used that as a sample process so that we didn't get hung up on the internal process itself.

Comment: This method works on all variables however many their are. If you wanted to choose a subset, it's not clear how you wanted to do that in your question. I've added an alternative method, but if you just need the column values to generate your stats, I really don't see why this wouldn't work. It your example isn't close enough to what you are really doing, it would help to improve it.

Comment: Ok, I think this definitely works for my example, and I think I can make it work....  But why are R programmers so against loops?  Is it a processing constraint?  What if i had a standard column 'Y' that I wanted to regress each variable against and collect stuff one at a time in addition to the other things?  in this case, I would want to loop through Y~[i] or something...which is closer to my use case.  I didn't want to get hung up on the specifics of the linear regression syntax, so I presented a more basic example.  Does that make sense?

Comment: This is a big question that's hard to answer in a comment be i'll try a quick answer. R programmers tend to prefer higher level, more expressive functions than for loops. Plus the higher levels functions are better at memory management by default. If you are not careful with memory allocations, it is possible to write an inefficient for loop whereas it's much more difficult to mess up in an apply or map function. We try to use functions that let us specify what we want to do rather than how we want to do it.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks for your help.  I am going to reword to include the scenario about regression, and ask another question...because I cannot see how I would use this approach to address that need.

Comment: Please don't meaningfully change answered questions. Ask a new one instead. But I'm sure you'll find many existing questions about looping over different regressive on this site already.